# Microcontroller ATMEGA328P ports

Tags: microcontroller

Hello I am fairly new to microcontrollers and would like to know how would one know if a port is analogic or digital? in function of their I/O ports.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you read the specsheet

Comment: I'll let you in on a little secret: some of the ports can be configured to be either analog or digital. Heck, you can even change the function dynamically using a program running on the ATmega.

Comment: Question can be answered by reading the datasheet and should be closed - insufficient research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf)  shows which port is digital only, and which is analog or digital.

Both graphically:

[image]

And in a table (shown only in part, see I/O multiplexing on the linked datasheet):

[image]